# laravel model relationship pivot on pivots?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have hit a problem in my web application, and I am hoping that some kind soul maybe able to offer me some help.

In my application I have users and organisation - an organisation can have **many** users and a user can have **many** organisations to my mind this represents a many-to-many relationship?

```
User n:m Organisation
```

Meaning that I require a pivot table? Let us call that Organisation_User. At the moment all seems simple enough, however my complication comes that a user in an organisation can have various roles,

1) Admin
2) Manager
3) Finance
4) Basic

The only rule with these roles is that admin superseeds everything else. My problem is that a user a can theoretically be a basic user and also a finance user in the same organisation. I am struggling to work how best to store this data, do I store it directly in the pivot table? Or do I create a pivot of the pivot something like `Organisation_User_Roles` and if that is the case, is that even possible in Laravel? How would that look?

Comment: Maybe add a column, for example, `role` to pivot table and set unique index as `user_organisation_role` smth like that?

Comment: That is all good, but a user can have multiple roles in an organisation, a role column could not represent this.

Comment: And could be a situation when the user have a finance role in an organization and haven't basic role?

Comment: Theoretically they could any combination of the 4 roles, but if they have admin in that combination, that overrules all other roles.

Answer (score 1):

Read the **Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns** section from

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

In your pivot table you can add an additional colum `roles` where you comma separate the roles (names or ids) and build a custom method `hasRole` in your models.

Beware though, this approach may have scalability problems!

---

The other way would be to create a `Role` model and an additional table `organisation_user_role` with the structure

```
organisation_id
user_id
role_id
```

In your `User` model build a method `hasRoleInOrganisation($role_id, $organisation_id)` that would query this table.

This approach doesn't have a Laravelish way if querying this table. You wil have to use:

```
DB::table('organisation_user_role')
    ->whereUserId($this->id)
    ->whereOrganisationId($organisation_id)
    ->whereRoleId($role_id)
    ->count();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have thought about these approaches, but neither feel like they will scale well, I am now thinking of, having a 1:n relation off my organisation_user table and working that way. What do you think to that?

Comment: i still don't get where you will have the roles associations. the only scalable way i see so far is the second approach i suggested.